# Linux system call not working on Linux kernel version 3.16.1

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am new to Operating Systems and have been trying to implement a system call in Linux kernel version 3.16.1. Mine is an Ubuntu 13.10 64-Bit system. My problem is that the system call is not returning the right value. The printk() call prints the value of i correctly but the value returned is -1 always.

Here is the procedure I followed:
Adding New System Call:

Kernel files modified:
(1) /usr/src/linux-3.16.0/arch/x86/syscalls/syscall_64.tbl

```
315 common  sched_getattr       sys_sched_getattr
316 common  renameat2       sys_renameat2
317 64  firstsyscall        sys_firstsyscall
```

(2) /usr/src/linux-3.16.0/include/linux/syscalls.h
This file has been updated as follows:

```
asmlinkage long sys_finit_module(int fd, const char __user *uargs, int flags);

 /*
My syscalls
*/
asmlinkage long sys_firstsyscall(int );

#endif
```

(3) /usr/src/linux-3.16.0/kernel/Makefile
This is the file:

```
#
# Makefile for the linux kernel.
#

    obj-y     = fork.o exec_domain.o panic.o \
    cpu.o exit.o itimer.o time.o softirq.o resource.o \
    sysctl.o sysctl_binary.o capability.o ptrace.o timer.o user.o \
    signal.o sys.o kmod.o workqueue.o pid.o task_work.o \
    extable.o params.o posix-timers.o \
    kthread.o sys_ni.o posix-cpu-timers.o \
    hrtimer.o nsproxy.o \
    notifier.o ksysfs.o cred.o reboot.o \
    async.o range.o groups.o smpboot.o firstsyscall.o
```

New Kernel files  created:

(1) /usr/src/linux-3.16.0/kernel/firstsyscall.c

```
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/linkage.h>
#include<linux/syscalls.h>

asmlinkage long sys_firstsyscall(int i){

    printk("Inside the system call, i= %d\n",i);
    return 2*i;
}
```

New User Space Files created

(1) /usr/include/firstsyscall.h

```
#include<unistd.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<sys/syscall.h>
#define __NR_firstsyscall 317   

long sys_firstsyscall(int i)
{

return syscall( __NR_firstsyscall,i);
}
```

(2) fsc_test.c (the program that contains test code for system call)

```
    #include<firstsyscall.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

int arg;
int retn;

printf("Enter the NUMBER:  ");
scanf("%d",&arg);


retn = sys_firstsyscall(arg);
printf("%d\n",retn);

return 0;
}
```

Thank You very much for your help in advance

Comment: Are you sure you're actually booting your rebuilt kernel and not the unmodified one? You could try adding a late_initcall function that just does a printk and make sure you see it in the dmesg output to confirm.

Comment: Also are you sure you compiled the kernel code base after making the changes ? The changes look fine. Check if your `firstsyscall.o` object file is getting built in the directory path after `make`. Next use command on `vmlinux` and look for the symbol.

Comment: Hello Gil, I am running the modified kernel. Also firstsyscall.o is being created. Yet for some reason, the syscall just won't work. even the printk fn call inside firstsyscall.c is never executed.